# Rails 3 and MongoDB encoding issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, cyrillic

My cached Russian (cyrillic) pages look like this:

Ð£ÑÐºÐ¾Ñ€ÑÐµÑ‚ÑÑ Ð¶Ð¸Ð·Ð½ÑŒ, ÑÑ‚Ð°Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð¸Ñ‚ÑÑ Ð»Ð°ÐºÐ¾Ð½Ð¸Ñ‡Ð½Ñ‹Ð¼ ÑÐ·Ñ‹Ðº. Ð Ð°Ð½ÑŒÑˆÐµ Ð¼Ñ‹ Ð³Ð¾Ð²Ð¾Ñ€Ð¸Ð»Ð¸: Ð½Ð°Ñ†Ð¸Ð¾Ð½Ð°Ð»ÑŒÐ½Ð¾-Ð¾ÑÐ²Ð¾Ð±Ð¾Ð´Ð¸Ñ‚ÐµÐ»ÑŒÐ½Ð°Ñ Ð±Ð¾Ñ€ÑŒÐ±Ð° Ð½Ð°Ñ€Ð¾Ð´Ð¾Ð² ÐÐ·Ð¸Ð¸, ÐÑ„Ñ€Ð¸ÐºÐ¸ Ð¸ Ð›Ð°Ñ‚Ð¸Ð½ÑÐºÐ¾Ð¹ ÐÐ¼ÐµÑ€Ð¸ÐºÐ¸, Ð° Ñ‚ÐµÐ¿ÐµÑ€ÑŒ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾ÑÑ‚Ð¾ - Ñ‚ÐµÑ€Ñ€Ð¾Ñ€Ð¸Ð·Ð¼.

I'm on rails 3.1, the database is mongodb. Can anyone tell me why this is so?